# DAG provider returns refresh error code 517

Tags: yodlee

Our team can't use the DAG right now.

When trying to add an item with the provider **DagBankSeCUrityQA - Bank** (14748) I get a refresh error code 517.

Example itemID: 15466424
Please assist.

Thanks,
Michael.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still getting this error let us know, it seems like you might be getting this error  due to some temporary issue during that time.